# A function works fine with one number, but not an array. What am I missing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, function, if-statement

Pardon my ignorance, but I'm very new to coding in python. I have a pretty simple function; it just needs to make a calculation based on b's relative location to a and c:

```
a = 6
b = 3
c = 2

def function(a, b, c):
    if ((a >= b) & (b >= c)):
        return b - c 
    elif ((a <= b) & (b >= c)):
        return a - c
    else:
        return 0 
t = function(a, b, c)
print(t)
```

When I run it with simple numbers like above, it gives me the right answer no matter what I make b. (In this case 1)

But When I run it with a,b, and c as Numpy Arrays, it only returns b - c across the entire "t" array.

It's not too much different, but here's what I'm using for the array version:

```
def function(a, b, c):
    if ((a >= b) & (b >= c)).any():
        return b - c 
    elif ((a <= b) & (b >= c)).any():
        return a - c
    else:
        return 0 
t = function(a, b, c[i>1])
print(t)
```

(The [i>1] is there because there is a variable amount of array input, and another function will be used for when [i = 0])

I've also tried this:
t = np.where(((prev2 >= Head_ELV) & (Head_ELV >= Bottom_ELV)).any, Head_ELV - Bottom_ELV, 0)
but ran into the same result.

Would a while-loop work better?

Comment: `np.any` is True if at least one of the rows evaluates to True. Are you sure that for your input all the rows of the condition evaluate to False?

Comment: Ah, ok. That explains why I was getting the output. Not all the rows equate to be false. I thought that was what `np.all()` did. I wasn't able to run it without `np.any` or `np.all` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need looping here as the problem can be solved using array operations. You could try the below, assuming the arrays are of the same length.

```
# import numpy to be able to work with arrays
import numpy as np

def function(a, b, c):
    # declare array t with only zeros
    t = np.zeros_like(a)

    # declare filters
    mask_1 = (a >= b) * (b >= c)
    mask_2 = (a <= b) * (b >= c)

    # modifying t based on the filters above
    t[mask_1] = (b - c)[mask_1]
    t[mask_2] = (a - c)[mask_2]
    return t

# example 2d arrays
a = np.array([[1800,5], [5,5]])
b = np.array([[3416,2], [3,4]])
c = np.array([[1714,2], [3,4]])

# run function
function(a, b, c)
```

Comment: I would only use `np.zeros_like` instead of `np.array([0] * len(a))`

Comment: Thanks @AndreySobolev, edited accordingly.

Comment: Hmmmmm. When I try running it, the resulting `t` is an array of zeros.

Comment: @DiscoDave do you have an example of what the 'a', 'b', 'c' arrays look like? Are they 1-dimension arrays or more? Any sample of them would help me figure out why you get back a 't' full of zeros.

Comment: They are 2-dimensional arrays. I want this program to be able to work with variable amounts of rows and columns. But I'm currently testing it with arrays that each have 94 rows and 66 columns. The character limit doesn't allow me to paste one here, hahaha.

Comment: But for example, at (r,c) = (0,0), a=1800, b =3416, and c=1714. The conditions for your mask_1 aren't met - a is not greater than b even though b is greater than c. BUT the conditions for your mask_2 ARE met. So at (0,0), t should output a-c; in this case 86. It's giving me zero as if b is less than both a and c, though.

Comment: @DiscoDave understood! In my code the 0th element is not handled as you mentioned in your original post you need another logic to apply where 'i = 0'. But let me edit my answer in a way where the logic will apply to all of the array, and then if that works then you can just handle the 0th element separately afterwards. I'm editing my answer above now accordingly, which returns np.array([[86, 0], [0, 0]]) with the given input arrays. Let me know how it works on your side!

Comment: It ended up working; thank you so much for the help!